# Check if xsd datetime had a defined timezone before conversion to Java object

Tags: java, xml, datetime, xsd, jaxb

Here's the topo, i have JAXB generated java classes from XSD files. For `xsd:datetime` type, the transformation goes through the [`public static Calendar javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(String lexicalXSDDateTime)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime%28java.lang.String%29) method.

I do not have access to the string value of the date (the one in the xml file), all i have access to is the generated `Calendar` object, and what i want to know, is whether in the original string value of the date, a timezone was defined or not.

For example, this string `2015-07-29T11:17:02.428+02:00` has a defined timezone, where this one `2015-07-29T11:17:02.428` have an undefined one, and all i want to know is which generated `Calendar` object had originally a defined timezone.

I tried the `Calendar.getTimeZone()` method, but it seems that the xsd to java transformation doesn't nullify the timezone.

As for example, the following code

```
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-07-29T11:17:02.428+02:00").getTimeZone());
System.out.println(DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime("2015-07-29T11:17:02.428").getTimeZone());
```

Outputs this

> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="GMT+02:00",offset=7200000,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
>
> sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted the answer to this question on my other question: [java - How to check if a Calendar instance was originally a wrong date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31717677/java-how-to-check-if-a-calendar-instance-was-originally-a-wrong-date/31721892#31721892).

The principle is to use JodaTime API and a custom Adapter and a custom wrapper type for the DateTime object.