# java - How to check if a Calendar instance was originally a wrong date

Tags: java, xml, web-services, parsing, jaxb

I have a Calendar instance, parsed from XSD datetime via the [`javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseDateTime(java.lang.String)) method by JAXB.

At runtime, i'm in a web service, and i want to know if the original xsd datetime was valid (month < 12, day < 31, 30, 29, 28 according to month ...ect) or not. Example: this is a valid date: `2015-07-30T09:32:05.543+02:00` and this is not: `2015-07-35T09:32:05.543+02:00`

I tried to use [`setLenient`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setLenient(boolean)) on the instance in the web service, but it doesn't seem to raise an exception when the original date was wrong.

Is there any way to do it? My guess is to tell JAXB to do it the right way in the `global.jaxb` file, here's the one i use right now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/>
        <xjc:serializable uid="-1"/>
        <jaxb:javaType name="java.util.Calendar" xmlType="xs:dateTime"
                       parseMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime"
                       printMethod="javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter.printDateTime"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.parse( "2015-07-35T09:32:05.543+02:00" ) 
    … catch ( DateTimeParseException e )
```

## java.time

The troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9.

Likewise, the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### `OffsetDateTime` & `DateTimeParseException`

To determine invalid date-time string, attempt to parse and trap for exception. Given that your inputs have an offset-from-UTC but not a time zone, parse as [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) objects. Invalid inputs throw [`DateTimeParseException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeParseException.html).

```
String inputGood = "2015-07-30T09:32:05.543+02:00" ;
String inputBad = "2015-07-35T09:32:05.543+02:00" ;

try{ 
    // Good
    OffsetDateTime odtGood = OffsetDateTime.parse( inputGood ) ;
    System.out.println( "odtGood.toString(): " + odtGood ) ;

    // Bad
    OffsetDateTime odtBad = OffsetDateTime.parse( inputBad ) ;
    System.out.println( "odtBad.toString(): " + odtBad ) ;
} catch ( DateTimeParseException e ) {
    System.out.println( e ) ;
}
```

See [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/DYNUUF).

> odtGood.toString(): 2015-07-30T09:32:05.543+02:00
>
> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-07-35T09:32:05.543+02:00' could not be parsed: Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 35

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using JodaTime's [`ISODateTimeFormat#dateTimeParser()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateTimeParser()) and custom Adapter in a [custom JAXB bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing4.html) file. JodaTime is much better API than the Calendar standard Java API, and it is non lenient by default.

I could have done the same for Calendar, but i should have defined all the formats myself, where JodaTime defines them already.

Here a code sample i made (it answers too to my other question: [Check if xsd datetime had a defined timezone before conversion to Java object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31697490/check-if-xsd-datetime-had-a-defined-timezone-before-conversion-to-java-object))

```
package com.app.adapter;
public class MyDatetimeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, DateTime> {
    private final static DateTimeFormatter DATETIME_FORMATTER = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime();
    private final static Pattern TIMEZONE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(\\+|\\-)[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}$");
    @Override
    public DateTime unmarshal(String string) throws Exception {
        string = string.trim();
            try { 
            DateTime tmp = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeParser().parseDateTime(string);

            if (string.charAt(string.length()-1) == 'Z' || TIMEZONE_PATTERN.matcher(string).find()) {
                return new CustomDateTime(tmp);
            }
            return new CustomDateTime(tmp, CustomDateTime.Error.NO_TIMEZONE);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            return new CustomDateTime(null, CustomDateTime.Error.INVALID);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(CustomDateTime date) throws Exception {
        return DATETIME_FORMATTER.print(date.getDateTime());
    }
}
```

And here's CustomDateTime (a POJO that wraps a JodaTime's DateTime and an error code)

```
package com.app.types;
public final class CustomDateTime {

    private DateTime dateTime;
    private Error error;

    // getter .. setters .. constructor

    public static CustomDateTime getInstance(Error error) {
        return new CustomDateTime(DateTime.now(), error);
    }

    public static CustomDateTime getInstance() {
        return getInstance(Error.NONE);
    }

    public enum Error {
        NONE,
        NO_TIMEZONE
        INVALID;
    }
}
```

And finally, the JAXB binding file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
               xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" jaxb:version="2.1">
    <jaxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:javaType adapter="com.app.adapter.MyDatetimeAdapter"
                      name="com.app.types.CustomDateTime" xmlType="xs:dateTime"/>
    </jaxb:globalBindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```